# Excel: Modify formula with VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a formula that is a simple sum of a view cells like `SUM(A1;A10;A20)`
I would like to have a button with a macro that changes this formula to add a new cell to the sum (for example A30).

Is there a way to do this via VBA?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use a helper column where you put an x in the row that you want to include and use: `=SUMIFS(A:A;Z:Z;"x")` where `Z:Z` is the helper column.

Comment: @ScottCraner cool that worked! if you add it as answer, I'll mark it as accepted :-) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple macro:

```
Sub Calc()
  Dim SourceCell As String
  Dim DestinationCell As String
  SourceCell = InputBox("Enter the source cell:","Microsoft Excel")
  DestinationCell = InputBox("Enter the destination cell:","Microsoft Excel")
  Range(SourceCell).Value = Range(SourceCell).Value + Range(DestinationCell).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: The OP wants to edit the formula not remove it and place the total value.

Comment: @ScottCraner isn't both same thing?

Comment: No, one leaves the `=A1+A2+A3` which is live and the value will change as the inputs change and the other leaves a static number that will not change as the inputs do.

Answer (score 0):

Although a sufficient solution has been given in the comments, here is an example of how to do what is originally asked.
There might be prettier ways of doing it, but the simple approach is; To retrieve the formula (with `.formula`), remove the end bracket (using `Left()`), add the cell we want and close it up again.

```
Sub addCell()
    Dim formula_str As String, source As Range
    Set source = Range("D2")
    formula_str = source.Formula
    source.Value = Left(formula_str, Len(formula_str) - 1) & "," & Selection.Address(False, False) & ")"
End Sub
```

The cell we are adding is the `Selection.Address`, meaning the current selection, but `(False, False)` removes the absolute reference. So "`A5`" rather than "`$A$5`".

[image]

Naturally, change `source` to be the cell containing the formula that needs to be updated.